# How to use NSPointArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbezierpath

So I want to use the method  `appendBezierPathWithPoints:count:` in NSBezierPath.  But the method requires me to use NSPointArray.   The documentary doesn't really talk much about it and all I could get about it is that it's an array of NSPoints and I'm not sure how to do it.  I think that it uses the c array mechanism, but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need a C-style array of points to pass to `appendBezierPathWithPoints:count:`. For example you might do something like this:

```
NSPoint pointArray[3];

pointArray[0] = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
pointArray[1] = NSMakePoint(0.5, 0.25);
pointArray[2] = NSMakePoint(1, 1);

[lines appendBezierPathWithPoints:pointArray count:3];
```

where `lines` is an instance of `NSBezierPath`.

In a more complicated case you'll use a variable number of points say.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Objective-C style array, then you have to use NSValue class for this purpose.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

CGPoint myPoint;
myPoint.x = 100;
myPoint.y = 200;

[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:myPoint]];
```

To retrieve an NSPoint back from the array:

```
myPoint = [array[0] pointValue];
```

Hope it helps.